# iOS app that uses multiple Facebook app IDs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an application that uses different Facebook apps (2 different AppIDs) to post on Facebook and to show that it's "via iPhone" / "via iPad".

When the Facebook application is installed on the device and the user wants to login with Facebook in my application, the Facebook app is launched - and it won't return to my application - in case of iPad.

I tried putting both those AppIDs in my plist (as fbxxxxxxxxx) in CFUrlScheme - and, in this case, it won't return to my app, no matter what the device is. If there's only the ID for the iPhone app, it works (only on iPhone, of course).

Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be of help. I have taken this from [IOS Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

> Updating Your Info.plist Settings
>
> Most of the existing keys in a universal app’s Info.plist file should
>   remain the same. However, for any keys that require different values
>   on iPhone versus iPad devices, you can add device modifiers to the key
>   name. When reading the keys of your Info.plist file, the system
>   interprets each key using the following format:
>
> key_root-~
>
> In this format, the key_root portion represents the original name of
>   the key. The  and  portions are both optional
>   endings that you can use for keys that are specific to a platform or
>   device. For apps that run only on iOS, you can omit the platform
>   string. (The iphoneos platform string is used to distinguish apps
>   written for iOS from those written for Mac OS X.) To apply a key to a
>   specific device, use one of the following values:
>
> ```
> iphone—The key applies to iPhone devices.
>
> ipod—The key applies to iPod touch devices.
>
> ipad—The key applies to iPad devices.
> ```
>
> For example, to indicate that you want your app to launch in a
>   portrait orientation on iPhone and iPod touch devices but in
>   landscape-right on iPad, you would configure your Info.plist with the
>   following keys:
>
> UIInterfaceOrientation
>
> UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
>
> UIInterfaceOrientation~ipad
>
> UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
>
> Notice that in the preceding example, there is an iPad-specific key
>   and a default key without any device modifiers. Continue to use the
>   default key to specify the most common (or default) value and add a
>   specific version with a device-specific modifier when you need to
>   change that value. This guarantees that there is always a value
>   available for the system to examine. For example, if you were to
>   replace the default key with an iPhone-specific and iPad-specific
>   version of the UIInterfaceOrientation key, the system would not know
>   the preferred starting orientation for iPod devices.
>
> For more information about the keys you can include in your Info.plist
>   file, see Information Property List Key Reference

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me. In the end I went right ahead and left both AppIDs in the plist and it *sort of* works. On the iPad it has a glitch - if you have the Facebook app installed, but you're not logged in, then your app won't receive focus again. However, if the FB is logged, then it returns back to my app. I guess that's enough for that I need.